# How to run set of Test Cases using Android's UI Automator

Tags: android, automation, android-uiautomator

I am working on Android's UI Automator to automate few test cases in my current Project.
Few Test Cases that I have written so far as individual public classes  under the package com.myapp.testautomation includes
Launch App from device Dashboard
New User Registration
Login
Logout
How do I runn all these cases at once and build a Test Suite?
Currently, I am individually running these cases by executing the following command 
adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.New User Registration
adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.Login
adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.Logout

Answer (score 0):

One Way I found to run multiple test cases is to execute a shell script including the tests cases  in it. For e.g

```
ant build
adb push /Users/xyz/Documents/workspace/ProjectXYZ/bin/ProjectXYZ.jar /data/local/tmp/
adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.NewUserRegistration 
adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.Login 
adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.Logout
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run all the tests from one class you can do this instead. (working from the user2040344's answer)

```
    ant build
    adb push /Users/xyz/Documents/workspace/ProjectXYZ/bin/ProjectXYZ.jar /data/local/tmp/
    adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.testCases#NewUserRegistration 
    adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.testCases#Login 
    adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.testCases#Logout
```

Notice there is a '#' between testCases and NewUserRegistration. This denotes that you are calling a method from the same class but only that one method. Everything else is the same except it allows you to have one class that controls all the test cases but you can still use them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest way would be to create a `.bat` file. and put all the commands in it. Have done this many times. This is the easiest way, e.g.:

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest dialler.jar -c sprd.performance.dialler.Dialler 
adb shell uiautomator runtest contactscroll.jar -c sprd.performance.contactscroll.ContactScroll
```

These are my two scripts to run. Create a `.bat` file for them and just double click on the `.bat` file.